# Can Jenkins issue a "maven jboss-as:deploy" on my project?

Tags: spring, maven, jboss, jenkins

I am trying to use Jenkins and Selenium for CI with my Spring Project that I will be running in AS7.

I would like to know if I can get Jenkins to issue a "maven jboss-as:deploy" command line on my project to deploy it to my AS7 server.

Can someone please let me know if this can be done..

Answer (score 0):

No need to involve Jenkins here. Just add the `jboss-as:deploy` plugin to your pom.xml, bound to the `pre-integration-test` phase of your build. Then when you run `mvn install` (either locally or on Jenkins), your war will be deployed to the AS7 server.

Comment: Thanks  Artbristol can you please tell me how to so that..  It sounds like something good. But what if I don't want to do it everytime I do a build?

Comment: Have a look at this blog entry http://maciejwalkowiak.pl/blog/2012/03/22/integration-tests-with-maven-3-failsafe-and-cargo-plugin/ (it's using Cargo but it's similar for the jboss plugin) ... you can put the plugin config in a separate profile if you don't want to run it every time (but you should run it every time!)